# How to split a String in Rust that I take as an input with read!()

Tags: rust

I want to split a `String` that I give as an input according to white spaces in it.
I have used the `split_whitespaces()` function but when I use this function on a custom input it just gives me the first `String` slice.

```
let s:String = read!();
let mut i:usize = 0;
for token in s.split_whitespace() {
    println!("token {} {}", i, token);
    i+=1;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `read!` is not a standard macro. A quick search reveals that is probably is from the [`text_io`](https://docs.rs/text_io/0.1.7/text_io) crate (if you are using external crates you should tell so in the question).

From the docs in that crate:

> The `read!()` macro will always read until the next ascii whitespace character (`\n`, `\r`, `\t` or space).

So what you are seeing is by design.

If you want to read a whole line from `stdin` you may try the standard function [`std::Stdin::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line).

Comment: thankyou so much. i am a fairly new rust programmer and i usually use the standard input i dont know why i didnt see this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing test cases which could locate the source of the problem. Split the code into a function and replace the `read!()`-macro with a test case, which you could put in main for now, where you provide different strings to the function and observe the output.

```
fn strspilit(s:String){
    let mut i:usize = 0;
    for token in s.split_whitespace() {
        println!("token {} {}", i, token);
        i+=1;
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    strspilit("Hello Huge World".to_string());

}
```

Then you will see your code is working as it should [but as notices in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58363474/391691) the read!() macro is only returning the string until the first white space so you should probably use another way of reading your input.

Comment: You're not actually solving the OP's problem - which stems from the `read!()` macro implementation details, as rodrigo's answer successfully points out. The problem is that, even though the code is correct, the macro used to capture input stops at the first whitespace.

Comment: OP would have identified where the problem was with the methodology of breaking it up into smaller parts